# HTML Frameset Query

Tags: html, frameset

I have the following code for framset display

```
<FRAMESET ROWS="18%,*" >
   <FRAME SRC="./views/Title_Page.html" NAME=TITLE SCROLLING=NO MARGINHEIGHT=1 noresize="noresize">

   <FRAMESET COLS="20%,*">
      <FRAME SRC="./views/Navigation_Page.jsp" NAME=SIDEBAR noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">
      <FRAME SRC="./views/Welcome.html" NAME=MAIN noresize="noresize">
   </FRAMESET>
<NOFRAMES>NOFRAMES stuff
</NOFRAMES> 

</FRAMESET>
```

I want to add a logout link which logges out of the app ,when i add a link in Title_Page.html it logges out only that frame but not the others,how will handle it?i want to log out completly from all the frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I must preface by saying that frames are pretty much frowned upon on the web these days. They're deprecated, they're not a good user experience, it's very difficult to link or bookmark a page, etc etc...*

Add `target="_top"` to your logout link. It will target the "top" page (the one which defines all the frames). Also note that `target` is deprecated.

Comment: where target="_top" as to b e added in frame defination ?

Comment: @sarah: in the logout link. `<a href="logout.jsp" target="_top">`

Answer (score 0):

```
target="_top"
```

… same as anything else you want to hit the top window instead of the current frame.